# Parsing data from a table from a website with null values

Tags: c#, linq, excel, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am a little new to using LINQ. What I am trying to do is pull data from a website with Japanese vocabulary. Within the table there are 3 cells. Occasionally some of the cells are blank because there is nothing needed there for the vocabulary.
I have used HTMLAgilityPack to pull the data from the website. However when I am trying to parse it, it shows an error saying it cannot have null values.

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/jlpt1/vocab/combined/");
        var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                    from row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                    from cell in table.SelectNodes("th|td").Cast<HtmlNode() //where cell != null
                    select new { Table = table.Id, cellText = cell.InnerText };
```

I'm not sure how to cast it so I will be able to parse the information how I have it now.
Eventually I want to use a foreach to put those cells into an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                    from row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                    from cell in table.SelectNodes("th|td").Cast<HtmlNode() //where cell != null
                    select new { Table = table.Id, cellText =cell==null?"":cell.InnerText??"" };
```

have you try this?

Comment: I did try something like that yeah. The issue is in this statement `from cell in table.SelectNodes("th|td").Cast<HtmlNode()` because it's calling the method before checking if it's null. I'm just not sure in LinQ how to fix this error. It doesn't get to the `select new { Table = table.Id, cellText =cell==null?"":cell.InnerText??"" };` part because it fails at the one above it.